# mysql details about tables

Tags: mysql, database

I know about `show tables` and `describe <table_name>` commends from mysql, but I'll like to know if thee is any solution which will show me all the tables from a database togheter with the number of columns from each table.

It that possible?

The thing is that i need to compare two databases (with 52 tables each), which seems to have the same structure, but I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very easy thing to do, MySQL keeps information about its databases in the **information_schema** database, this acts as the metadata for MySQL so you can find pretty much any information you need provided you have the right privileges to access that database.
I just tested this on MySQL 5.1.54, run it in any database to get the tables with their associated number of columns

```
SELECT table_name, COUNT(column_name) AS num_columns 
FROM information_schema.statistics S     
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
GROUP BY table_name
ORDER BY table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

If your user has the permissions, you can query the database "information_schema", table "COLUMNS".

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of MySQL you can take a look at the `INFORMATION SCHEMA`: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `PHPMyadmin`, check for `Data Dictionary` option at the bottom on database structure tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare your databases and view differences with [Schema Comparison tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Stand-alone tool - [dbForge Schema Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/schemacompare/)